# Is Kafka Java Consumer Client single threaded

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

We are getting started with Kafka,
While reading this  - https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-clients/java/current/overview.html - it seemed to imply that the client is single-threaded.

*

> Due to this *single-threaded model*, no heartbeats can be sent while the
> application is handling the records returned from a call to poll().
> This means that the consumer will fall out of the consumer group if
> either the event loop terminates or if a delay in record processing
> causes the session timeout to expire before the next iteration of the
> loop.

- 

Does this mean that Kafka really expects only one thread per provcess/JVM ?
Also how does Spring enable concurrency for listeners ? ( Does it open a TCP connection to the Kafka server for each concurrent thread ( Eg :- open 5 independent TCP connection for **factory.setConcurrency(5)** ) ? )

Comment: Yes. There's also https://github.com/confluentinc/parallel-consumer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assumption is almost correct. The Apache Kafka recommends to have a single thread per partition in the topic. Or better to say: no one partition can be handled by different threads. However same thread can handle several partitions. That's what they call as a `subscription`. So, single `KafkaConsumer` can process several partitions (even from different topics) in a single thread.

The concurrency works a bit different than you think: no more then available partitions. So, if you have two partitions in one topic, then only two concurrent `KafkaConsumer` instances are active. All others are just idling within the same consumer group.

So, technically yes: `open 5 independent TCP connection`, but that doesn't mean that all of them are consuming records from topics.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @artembilan. That makes sense. I did know that the maximum number of subscribers is limited by the maximum number of partitions. But I forgot the fact that same is also a limit on the number of threads there can be.